# Symfony forms : collection of formtype field not mapping

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Considering the following architecture

```
entityA
{
    entityB [12]
}

entityB
{
    entityC[]
}

entityC
{
   name, defaultValue
}
```

When creating a new object of entityA I want to list every entityC in database to be able to select them and customize defaultValue like following :

```
CHECKBOX [x] LABEL name1, INPUT defaultValue1
CHECKBOX [ ] LABEL name2, INPUT defaultValue2
CHECKBOX [x] LABEL name3, INPUT defaultValue3
CHECKBOX [x] LABEL name4, INPUT defaultValue4
etc
```

... the aim is to generate automatically entityC objects according the selection above, in every one of the 12 entityB objects of this new entityA

```
->add('categories', CollectionType::class, [
    "mapped" => false,
    'entry_type'    => SharedCategoryType::class
])
```

Using Category (entityC) as an entitytype is not working because I want to expose default value too. Here's SharedCategoryType

```
class SharedCategoryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('enabled', CheckboxType::class, [
                "mapped" => false
            ])
            ->add('name' , TextType::class) //not a label but not important for now
            ->add('defaultValue' , MoneyType::class); 
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Category::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

With this code the mapping is not working, but I don't know what is missing...

Edit : the first attemps I made was like this :

```
->add('budgets', EntityType::class, [
            "class" => Category::class,
            "mapped" => false,
            "multiple" => true,
            "expanded" => true
}
```

but then I cannot modify the defaultValue field. It automatically creates the label based on the name (using the __toString method I defined probably), but I can't find how to add defaultValue to the fields exposed

Answer (score 0):

If you create a related entity, you can use the form event eg

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  ...
  $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) 
  {
            /** @var ResultModel $model */
            $model = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            if (!$model->getExecutive()) {
                $form->add('executive', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => BundesligaExecutive::class,
                    'placeholder' => 'bundesliga.executive.choose',
                    'help' => 'bundesliga.executive.help',
                ]);
            } 
...
}
```

Here find more details https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

By the way, it is probably a better idea to use a selectBox instead of checkboxes